# Host key verification failed please make sure you have the correct access rights

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to run the command `npm install` and in my `package.json` file I have the following dependency.
`"abc-editor": "git+ssh://git@abc.bitbucket.org:abc-apps/editor.git"`

I tried many solutions online which says I need to add ssh key and I followed [here](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.13/user/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) to do so.

but I am still getting the same error and after hours of different techniques, I am stuck. what should I do here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+Host+key+verification+failed

Comment: Please note: **Host** key, not **user** key.